# Identity for projection and inclusion of the canonical one-form on the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, tangent-bundle

I'm currently reading through *Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry* by Marsden and Ratiu, specifically the section on Cotangent bundles. I'm trying to do the following exercise:

> Let $N$ be a submanifold of $M$ and denote by $\Theta_N$ and
> $\Theta_M$ the canonical one-forms on the cotangent bundles
> $\pi_N: T^*N\to N$ and $\pi_M: T^*M\to M$, respectively. Let $\pi: (T^*M)|N\to T^*N$ be the projection defined by
> $\pi(\alpha_n)=\alpha_n|T_nN$, where $n\in N$ and $\alpha\in T^*_nM$.
> Show that $\pi^*\Theta_N=i^*\Theta_M$ where $i:(T^*M)|N\to T^*M$ is
> the inclusion.

I believe we have $\pi^*\Theta_N(v)=\Theta_N(\pi_* v)$. I believe that $\pi_* v$ just turns $v\in T_\alpha(T^*M)$ into an element of $T_\alpha(T^*N)$ by removing whatever part of it was in $T_nM$. Is it true that $i_* v$ does the same thing, i.e. it takes a vector in $T_\alpha(T^*M)$ and turns it into a vector in $T_\alpha(T^*N)$? If not, how would I go about showing the identity in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your questions:

> I believe that $\pi_*v$ just turns $v\in T_\alpha(T^*M)$ into an element of $T_\alpha(T^*N)$ by removing whatever part of it was in $T_nM$.

I don't really know what this means - there's no `part' of $\pi_*v$ in $T_nM$.

> Is it true that $i_*v$ does the same thing, i.e. it takes a vector in $T_\alpha(T^*M)$  and turns it into a vector in $T_\alpha(T^*N)$?

Not quite. In Marsden and Ratiu's notation, the vector would be $T_\alpha i(v)$ ($i_*$ is reserved for vector fields). Then we have
$$
i:(T^*M)\vert N\to T^*M \implies T_\alpha i :T_\alpha ((T^*M)\vert N)\to T_{i(\alpha)}(T^*M).
$$

The way to prove this result is to use the definitions of the canonical one-forms, along with the identity
$$
\pi_N\circ \pi = \pi_M\circ i
$$
(both sides map $\alpha_n\in (T^*M)\vert N$ to $n\in N$). Then for any $\alpha \in (T^*M)\vert N$ and $v_\alpha \in T_\alpha((T^*M)\vert N)$
\begin{align*}
(\pi^*\Theta_N)_\alpha(v_\alpha) &= (\Theta_N)_{\pi(\alpha)}(T_\alpha\pi(v_\alpha)) \\
&= \pi(\alpha)(T_{\pi(\alpha)}\pi_N(T_\alpha\pi(v_\alpha))) \qquad\text{by the definition of $\Theta_N$}\\
&= (\alpha\vert TN)(T_\alpha(\pi_N\circ \pi)(v_\alpha)) \qquad\text{by the chain rule}\\
&= i(\alpha)(T_\alpha(\pi_M\circ i)(v_\alpha)) \qquad\text{by the above identity}\\
&= i(\alpha)(T_{i(\alpha)}\pi_M(T_\alpha i(v_\alpha))) \qquad \text{by the chain rule}\\
&= (\Theta_M)_{i(\alpha)}(T_\alpha i(v_\alpha)) \qquad\text{by the definition of $\Theta_M$}\\
&= (i^*\Theta_M)_\alpha(v_\alpha).
\end{align*}
Hence $\pi^*\Theta_N = i^*\Theta_M$.